# How can I add events to a dynamically created PictureBox? (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling

As you can see, This is my current code for making pictureboxes. Basically, I am going to make about a hundred of them, so doing it by hand will be a giant pain. I don't know how to add events though, how do you do it?

Comment: What the images aren't uploaded?

Comment: Hold on https://www.dropbox.com/s/japjavja0hkl64f/Screenshot%20%281265%29.png?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4wcjg1d3vmmxn4/Screenshot%20%281266%29.png?dl=0

Comment: You need to take the tour as you were prompted. Images of code are never acceptable. Post your relevant code as part of your question and be sure to format it as code.

Comment: *"I don't know how to add events though"*. So search the web for that information. It's a very common thing to do and the information is very easy to find. SP is a place to get help with issues that you can't solve on your own, not ones that you can't be bothered to solve on your own. Post here when you have exhausted every other avenue, not as a first option.

Comment: Well, I tried to, but they always failed, and I found out that SP asks the same types of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class frmScreen
    Inherits Form
    Dim CellColor As PictureBox
    '
    '
    '

```
Private Sub Screen_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CellColor = New PictureBox
    With CellColor
        .BackColor = Color.Azure
        '
        '
        '
    End With

    'When you do click on the CellColor control the you go to ScreenPicBox method
    AddHandler CellColor.Click, AddressOf ScreenPicBox_Checked

    'If you need to remove by code the handler you can write the following instruction
    RemoveHandler CellColor.Click, AddressOf ScreenPicBox_Checked

End Sub

Private Sub ScreenPicBox_Checked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If TypeOf sender Is PictureBox Then
        'do anything here
    End If


End Sub
```

End Class

I hope that it shows the way you want, Darp mosh. Happy coding! :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm just a newbie so this will help!

Comment: Great, Darp mosh!, I am new too and it is a very long journey, but very awesome and great. Thank you for your response.